# How to read in seg file in matlab

Tags: matlab

how do I read in a ".seg" file into matlab? Here is my code:

```
image = imread('33039.seg');
```

The error I am recieving is :

```
Error using imread (line 362)
Unable to determine the file format.
```

Comment: matlab does not recognize `seg` as a known format for storing images and therefore unable to read your image in that format.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so please accept my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since .seg files are just tab-delimited text files, you could rename the file manually to a .txt file and use `textscan` to import the data into a cell array.

For instance, I was able to import the sample .seg file [here](http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/sites/cancerinformatics.org.igv/files/linked_files/example.seg) using the following code:

```
fid = fopen('example.txt');
fmt = '%s %d %d %d %d %f';
C = textscan(fid, fmt, 'HeaderLines', 1);
```

This code imports the data into a cell array `C` where each cell holds a vector with all the data from each column. The `fmt` variable specifies the format of your data import. In this case, the data is a string, followed by 4 integers, followed by a floating point number, hence `%s %d %d %d %d %f`. You may have to customize this depending on how your data looks.

Comment: There is no need to change the extension to txt to use textscan